warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
1149 |       yyerror (YY_("syntax error"));
enter image description here
any one can help me to resolve the issue
